# How to add myFaces Tomahawk to my JSF 2.0 (.jsp) running in glassfish 3?

Tags: jsf, glassfish-3, web.xml, tomahawk

Hi I been having some problems with my web.xml file
I've been getting:

```
Exception while loading the app
org.glassfish.deployment.common.DeploymentException: LLog;
    at org.glassfish.weld.WeldDeployer.event(WeldDeployer.java:169)
    at org.glassfish.kernel.event.EventsImpl.send(EventsImpl.java:125)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ApplicationInfo.load(ApplicationInfo.java:224)
    at  com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:338)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:183)
    at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:272)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$1.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:305)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:320)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1176)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$900(CommandRunnerImpl.java:83)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1235)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1224)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.doCommand(AdminAdapter.java:365)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.service(AdminAdapter.java:204)
    at com.sun.grizzly.tcp.http11.GrizzlyAdapter.service(GrizzlyAdapter.java:166)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.HK2Dispatcher.dispath(HK2Dispatcher.java:100)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:245)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:791)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:693)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:954)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:170)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:135)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:102)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:88)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:76)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:53)
    at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:57)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:69)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:330)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:309)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: LLog;
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Class.java:2291)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields(Class.java:1743)
    at org.jboss.weld.introspector.jlr.WeldClassImpl.<init>(WeldClassImpl.java:224)
    at org.jboss.weld.introspector.jlr.WeldClassImpl.of(WeldClassImpl.java:133)
    at org.jboss.weld.resources.ClassTransformer$2.call(ClassTransformer.java:72)
    at org.jboss.weld.resources.ClassTransformer$2.call(ClassTransformer.java:68)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.collections.ConcurrentCache.putIfAbsent(ConcurrentCache.java:125)
    at org.jboss.weld.resources.ClassTransformer.loadClass(ClassTransformer.java:67)
    at org.jboss.weld.introspector.jlr.WeldClassImpl.<init>(WeldClassImpl.java:156)
    at org.jboss.weld.introspector.jlr.WeldClassImpl.of(WeldClassImpl.java:133)
    at org.jboss.weld.resources.ClassTransformer$2.call(ClassTransformer.java:72)
    at org.jboss.weld.resources.ClassTransformer$2.call(ClassTransformer.java:68)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.collections.ConcurrentCache.putIfAbsent(ConcurrentCache.java:125)
    at org.jboss.weld.resources.ClassTransformer.loadClass(ClassTransformer.java:67)
    at org.jboss.weld.BeanManagerImpl.createAnnotatedType(BeanManagerImpl.java:1475)
    at org.glassfish.weld.WeldDeployer.fireProcessInjectionTargetEvents(WeldDeployer.java:236)
    at org.glassfish.weld.WeldDeployer.event(WeldDeployer.java:166)
    ... 30 more
  Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Log
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:200)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:188)
    at org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClass(WebappClassLoader.java:949)
    at  org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1420)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(ClassLoader.java:316)
    ... 52 more
```

I have imported the jar and the tags work! but the web.xml mapping keeps falling

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
    <param-value>Development</param-value>
</context-param>
<filter>
<filter-name>MyFacesExtensionsFilter</filter-name>
<filter-class>org.apache.myfaces.webapp.filter.ExtensionsFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>uploadMaxFileSize</param-name>
            <param-value>20m</param-value>
        </init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>MyFacesExtensionsFilter</filter-name>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
</filter-mapping>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>MyFacesExtensionsFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/faces/myFacesExtensionResource/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>
        30
    </session-timeout>
</session-config>
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>faces/welcomeJSF.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

project\build\web\WEB-INF\lib\tomahawk20-1..1-10.jar (location)

I imagen its basic but I'm not sure what I'm forgetting to do.

Best
Regards
Thank you
Ignacio

Comment: Is that really the full exception message? Just `Log`? Regardless, do you have installed all required [Tomahawk 2.0 dependencies](http://myfaces.apache.org/tomahawk-project/tomahawk20/dependencies.html) as well?

Comment: just log to point java.lang.ClassNotFoundException. I do  no hat all dependencies

Comment: I added al dependencies except javax.servelet jstl, is it ok? do I need the transitive as well?

Comment: Yes, it is fine. Servlet and JSTL should be already provided by Glassfish itself. As to the problem, sorry but with such an exception I am pretty lost. Especially the exception message is not informative enough. Seems to be related to Weld (the CDI implementation). Did it work all fine before you added Tomahawk?

Comment: yes it did, I have not used the file sin the src zip file. I dowloaded itm but i have no used it. Should I place those files somewhere? I'm not user with <url-pattern>/faces/myFacesExtensionResource/*</url-pattern>
shouldn't I put a path there?

Comment: should place those jars in both the glassfish and the app WEB-INF?

Comment: ...\nbproject\build-impl.xml:610: The module has not been deployed.
BUILD FAILED (total time: 51 seconds) netbeans log at startup

Comment: Only in `WEB-INF/lib` ought to be sufficient. Your `web.xml` is fine. Glad you fixed it though. Weird stuff...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the project back from CVS, deployed JARs altogether and copy/pasted `web.xml` and it worked! Go figure!