# org.glassfish.deployment.common.DeploymentException: LLog;

Tags: java, jsf, glassfish

Can some one tell me when de following is thrown and if I can recover from it?

```
org.glassfish.deployment.common.DeploymentException: LLog;
    at org.glassfish.weld.WeldDeployer.event(WeldDeployer.java:169)
    at org.glassfish.kernel.event.EventsImpl.send(EventsImpl.java:125)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ApplicationInfo.load(ApplicationInfo.java:224)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:338)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:183)
    at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:272)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$1.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:305)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:320)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1176)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$900(CommandRunnerImpl.java:83)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1235)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1224)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.doCommand(AdminAdapter.java:365)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.service(AdminAdapter.java:204)
    at com.sun.grizzly.tcp.http11.GrizzlyAdapter.service(GrizzlyAdapter.java:166)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.HK2Dispatcher.dispath(HK2Dispatcher.java:100)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:245)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:791)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:693)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:954)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:170)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:135)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:102)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:88)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:76)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:53)
    at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:57)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:69)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:330)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:309)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: LLog;
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Class.java:2291)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields(Class.java:1743)
    at org.jboss.weld.introspector.jlr.WeldClassImpl.<init>(WeldClassImpl.java:224)
    at org.jboss.weld.introspector.jlr.WeldClassImpl.of(WeldClassImpl.java:133)
    at org.jboss.weld.resources.ClassTransformer$2.call(ClassTransformer.java:72)
    at org.jboss.weld.resources.ClassTransformer$2.call(ClassTransformer.java:68)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.collections.ConcurrentCache.putIfAbsent(ConcurrentCache.java:125)
    at org.jboss.weld.resources.ClassTransformer.loadClass(ClassTransformer.java:67)
    at org.jboss.weld.introspector.jlr.WeldClassImpl.<init>(WeldClassImpl.java:156)
    at org.jboss.weld.introspector.jlr.WeldClassImpl.of(WeldClassImpl.java:133)
    at org.jboss.weld.resources.ClassTransformer$2.call(ClassTransformer.java:72)
    at org.jboss.weld.resources.ClassTransformer$2.call(ClassTransformer.java:68)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.collections.ConcurrentCache.putIfAbsent(ConcurrentCache.java:125)
    at org.jboss.weld.resources.ClassTransformer.loadClass(ClassTransformer.java:67)
    at org.jboss.weld.BeanManagerImpl.createAnnotatedType(BeanManagerImpl.java:1475)
    at org.glassfish.weld.WeldDeployer.fireProcessInjectionTargetEvents(WeldDeployer.java:236)
    at org.glassfish.weld.WeldDeployer.event(WeldDeployer.java:166)
    ... 30 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Log
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:200)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:188)
    at org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClass(WebappClassLoader.java:949)
    at org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1420)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(ClassLoader.java:316)
    ... 52 more
```

Thank you very much

Comment: You've had this before: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4963383/how-to-add-myfaces-tomahawk-to-my-jsf-2-0-jsp-running-in-glassfish-3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reinstalled glassfish adn netbeans 6.8 eight and it works (without tomahawk dou!

Answer (score 1):

The error is thrown while Glassfish is trying to deploy your application.  Since the deployment is failing, you application never reaches a runnable state.

From the log, it appears that you are missing a library dependency in your application.  You need to review the frameworks you are using and make sure that all dependencies exist either as part of your application (WEB-INF/lib) or as part of the Glassfish system libraries.

Comment: It runned ok until I made a bean for t:inputFileUpload and made a change in faces-config.xml, is there a way to check which library is it?

Comment: It is hard to tell from the error log itself.  I would recommend going through the dependency list at http://myfaces.apache.org/tomahawk-project/tomahawk20/dependencies.html and make sure everything is being included in your web app.  If you are missing some dependencies, add one at a time to see if the error is removed.  These errors are difficult to identify the exact source without a lot of research.